# Unir celdas en php o javascript de una tabla resultante de una query

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla generada en php a partir de una consulta en bbdd. Los resultados se muestran por líneas (con un while). Lo que me gustaría es que si en una columna el resultado es el mismo tener combinada la celda.

Adjunto dibujo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora con datos para que se vea mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla aparece a través de ajax cuando se pulsa un botón.
El código sigue la siguiente estructura:

```
$consulta = SELECT convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date, MJ.preventradalote,103)),103) AS PREV_ENTRADA_LOTE, convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date, MJ.prevsalidalote,103)),103) AS PREV_SALIDA_LOTE,
        MJ.EstadoFabrica, MJ.ProductionLot, MJ.AREAENVIO, MJ.Nombre, MJ.Obra, MJ.NumeroPedido,convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date, MJ.FechaEntregaPrevista,103)),103) AS FECHA_ENTREGA_PREVISTA, MJ.Nomenclatura, MJ.Descripcion,
            MJ.Color, MJ.Tipologia, MJ.Cantidad, MJ.Postes, MJ.numHojas, MJ.CajonPersiana, MJ.UdsConVidrio, MJ.TiempoFB_Linea
                FROM TBLH_TEST_MJL MJ WHERE MJ.FechaEstimadaSalidaTaller BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin' ORDER BY MJ.preventradalote DESC

if (obdc_num_rows($consulta)>0){

<table id="tabla_resultados">

<tr>
    <th  class = "B" style="width:75px">FEC EST SALIDA 
                              TALLER</th>
                            <th class = "B" style="width:40px">SEM ENTR</th>
                            <th class = "B" style="width:65px">AREA 
                              ENV&Iacute;O</th>
                            <th class = "B" style="width:200px">NOMBRE</th>
                            <th class = "B" style="width:200px">OBRA</th>
                            <th class = "B" 
                              style="width:200px">TIPOLOG&Iacute;A</th>
                            <th class = "B"style="width:150px">COLOR</th>
</tr>
    while ($rowConsulta = odbc_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $fechaEstimadaSalidaTaller=$rowConsulta['FECHA_ESTIMADA_SALIDA_TALLER'];
        $semanaEntrega=$rowConsulta['SemanaEntrega'];
        $areaEnvio=$rowConsulta['AREAENVIO'];
        $nombre=$rowConsulta['Nombre'];
        $obra=$rowConsulta['Obra'];
        $tipologia=$rowConsulta['Tipologia'];
        $color=$rowConsulta['Color'];

      --creo las filas para cada variable
        <tr>


                        <td class = "CF" style="width:75px" ><?php echo                     
                          htmlentities($fechaEstimadaSalidaTaller);?></td>
                        <td class = "C" style="width:65px"><?php echo 
                          htmlentities($semanaEntrega);?></td>
                        <td class = "D" style="width:65px"><?php echo 
                          htmlentities($areaEnvio);?></td>
                        <td class = "C" style="width:200px"><?php echo 
                          htmlentities($nombre);?></td>
                        <td class = "D"style="width:200px"><?php echo 
                          htmlentities($obra);?></td>
                        <td class = "C" style="width:200px"> <?php echo 
                          htmlentities($tipologia);?></td>
                        <td class = "D" style="width:150"><?php echo 
                        htmlentities($color);?></td>

         </tr>
}


}
```

Lo que he intentado es para probar en el campo $semanaEntrega tener una variable auxiliar $sem que compare y si es así unir con un rowspan las celdas. Previamente he definido un $contador para saber cuántas celdas de la columna tendría que unir. El problema es que cada vez el bucle itera me crea el td.

```
</tr>

 <?php
                                $contador=1;
                                $sem=0;
                                while ($rowConsulta = odbc_fetch_array($sqlConsulta)){

                            $fechaEstimadaSalidaTaller=$rowConsulta['FECHA_ESTIMADA_SALIDA_TALLER'];
                            $semanaEntrega=$rowConsulta['SemanaEntrega'];
                            $sem=$semanaEntrega;

                            $areaEnvio=$rowConsulta['AREAENVIO'];
                            $nombre=$rowConsulta['Nombre'];
                            $obra=$rowConsulta['Obra'];
                            $tipologia=$rowConsulta['Tipologia'];
                            $color=$rowConsulta['Color'];

?>                  
                    <tr>


                        <td class = "CF" style="width:75px" ><?php echo htmlentities($fechaEstimadaSalidaTaller);?></td>

                        <?php
                            if ($sem==$semanaEntrega){

                            ?>
                                    <td class = "C" style="width:65px" rowspan="<?php echo $contador;?>"><?php echo htmlentities($semanaEntrega);?></td>
                            <?php
                                $contador++;
                                }else{

                            ?>
                                    <td class = "C" style="width:65px"><?php echo htmlentities($semanaEntrega);?></td>
                            <?php
                                $contador=1;
                            }
                            ?>

                        <td class = "D" style="width:65px"><?php echo htmlentities($areaEnvio);?></td>
                        <td class = "C" style="width:200px"><?php echo htmlentities($nombre);?></td>
                        <td class = "D"style="width:200px"><?php echo htmlentities($obra);?></td>
                        <td class = "C" style="width:200px"> <?php echo htmlentities($tipologia);?></td>
                        <td class = "D" style="width:150"><?php echo htmlentities($color);?></td>
```

Esto lo que me hace es crear cada vez que itera el bucle la celda... y descuadra la tabla. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se me ocurre la manera de poder unir las celdas cuando tienen el mismo resultado. Creo que en la consulta con un group by tampoco valdría. Solo se me ocurre a través del DOM Javascript pero no sé la manera de hacerlo. ¿Alquien podría guiarme un poco?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es recorrer primero toda la estructura e ir añadiendo un campo adicional (o en otra variable), para cada campo de cada fila, que sea el número de columnas con valor igual, lo cual no sabrás hasta que lo recorras, por eso lo hay que hacer antes de mostrarlo. Después solo quedará añadir el `colspan` correspondiente que has calculado previamente.

Comment: Lo intenté previamente con un contador para saber el número de rowspan (celdas) que debería unir pero el problema es que creo el td todo el rato.. He adjuntado en el post el código que puse y la imagen que me sale.

Comment: Así no puede ser, debes recorrerlo previamente y anotar en cuantas **filas** (no columnas como dije antes) se repite el valor del campo por cada **columna**. 

Por ejemplo, anotas en una matriz (`$span[cant_col,cant_regs]`); por cada `$columna` llevas un `$contador`; si el valor del campo es diferente al anterior entonces `$span[$columna,$ultima_posicion[$columna]] = $contador[$columna]` y reseteas `$contador[$columna]=0` sino `$contador[$columna]++`; 

Después usaras estos valores almacenados en `$span` para el `rowspan` de cada celda (**NO COLSPAN COMO DIJE ANTES**)